# combining regex in c++

Tags: c++, regex, replace

I want to replace everything in a line except for alphabets, numbers and periods with whitespaces in c++.

Could anyone please give me a regex in c++ that I can use ?

I was using `[^[:alnum:]]` till now but that works only for alpha and numeric.

Thank you !

Comment: `except for alphabets, numbers and periods with whitespaces` ... can you show us an example?

Comment: I think you just need to add a period to your character class: `[^[:alnum:].]`

Comment: @Galik Careful, that dot needs to be escaped AFAIK.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can't check it at the moment but I thought inside `[]` only `[`, `]`, `-` and `\\` needed escaping.

Comment: @Galik I think you're right.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the dot don't need to be escaped in a character class (as the other special characters that loose there special meaning in this situation)

Comment: Try [`regex("[^[:alnum:][:space:].]+")`](https://ideone.com/jTSeCB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::replace_if(line.begin(), line.end(),
    [](char ch){ return !isalnum(ch) && ch != '.'; }, ' ');
```

No need to argue about escapes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a C++ person, but you can try adding dots to the regex:

```
[^[:alnum:].]
```

An alternative:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9.]
```

Comment: I think that Gayathri Jeyaram want to replace all that isn't an (alphanumeric or a dot) with white-space (probably a space), I'm not sure you need to include `\s`.